# Import ONNX model to tensorflow-ValidationError: BatchNormalization.scale in initializer but not in graph input

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, azure-machine-learning-service

I have downloaded ONNX model form CustomVision.ai and now I want to import into tensorflow and I am follwing "https://github.com/onnx/tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/OnnxTensorflowImport.ipynb" for guidance.

I have installed all the prerequisites as discussed in the above link. I am facing an error while executing "tf_rep = prepare(model)"---ValidationError: BatchNormalization.scale in initializer but not in graph input

```
import onnx
from onnx_tf.backend import prepare
model = onnx.load('C:\\Pankaj\\XYZ\\abc.onnx')
tf_rep = prepare(model)
```

Thank you for your help and time.